# tListView, XE6, BaaS: How to get Strings in nested objects

Tags: json, delphi, tlistview, mbaas

i'm new to Delphi XE6, VisualBinding and BaaS-Providers. I've been very happy to see, how easy it is to translate the JSON-Response from a tBackendQuery to a list view. My BaasStorage contains a column named FilePDF which contains a picture (a JPG, of yes, has to be renamed..). What I get back in the query is a URL to the file in the internet. How can I get this URL in a seperate variable?  (My quick-and-dirty-solution is to walk through a memo that displays the JSON-response and grab every "1+(ix*15)+6"th line.....

I wanted to show a screenshot, but I don't have enough reputations....
so here is the JSON-REspone....

```json
[
    {
    "FilePDF":
    {
      "__type":"File",
      "name":"tfss-xxxx.jpg",
      "url":"http://files.parsetfss.com/xxxx/xxxx.jpg"
    }
,
    "Title":"WS.01.01",
    "createdAt":"2014-08-16T07:25:39.968Z",
    "updatedAt":"2014-08-22T21:09:03.427Z",
    "objectId":"sCL4Yu9koB"
  }
,

  {
    "FilePDF":
    {
      "__type":"File",
      "name":"tfss-yyyy.jpg",
      "url":"http://files.parsetfss.com/yyyy/yyyy.jpg"
    }
,
    "Title":"WS.00.02",
    "createdAt":"2014-08-16T07:26:57.781Z",
    "updatedAt":"2014-08-22T21:17:59.531Z",
    "objectId":"o1nwtczraa"
  }

]
```

(there seems to be a tutorial by Sarina Dupont, but the link doesn't work...)

Comment: You cannot rely on the line number of a JSON-String, but you can get the values with a JSON-Parser (f.i. using [superobject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/))